# EE certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:1131)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

I am using the python 3.8 client example on my Modbus application, but I get an error like this:

```
    self._sock = context.wrap_socket(self._sock, server_hostname=self._host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: EE certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:1131)
```

I added the connection codes:

```
 def _do_open(self):
        """Connect to the Modbus slave"""
        if self._sock:
            self._sock.close()
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_timeout(self.get_timeout())
        self._sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        call_hooks("modbus_tcp.TcpMaster.before_connect", (self, ))
        context = SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
        # context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
        # context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

        context.load_verify_locations('cert.pem')
        context.check_hostname = False
        # context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        # with create_connection((self._host, self._port)) as self._sock:
        self._sock.connect((self._host, self._port))
        # time.sleep(4)
        # print("db:1")
        self._sock = context.wrap_socket(self._sock, server_hostname=self._host)
        #         # print("db:2")
        # call_hooks("modbus_tcp.TcpMaster.after_connect", (self, ))
```

If I added `context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE` line for the workaround, it works succefuly but it is not correct way. How Can I solve the problem ?

This is Certificate and Key in Server; (Example key and cert which I found on the github)

```
const char *privkey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"\
    "MIIBUwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT0wggE5AgEAAkEAhD0FKNdH91c8Vis0\n"\
    "T7Pli3Grb+BM5xA1V/iNTGer5WSwJlAab6lJ6NNh7R15AXOO7XODOs58ikmEqgWi\n"\
    "wacQfwIDAQABAkAG4KeSirPO/OYB80hKtugC2xwX+vn08IZdt2sd5Kxvhzvmp9eM\n"\
    "F4QhlQLHOMrk5LkM7FF0G3FgZHlOAZAVbQTtAiEA6SOLWEpnCCEkkCLMmZTcwzV0\n"\
    "cX9c7ngnOF/xwIn8IT0CIQCRNJVZ3YcJoXFuOCdUid8qOqdatCDkV8TQNxXxPVSc\n"\
    "awIgR1fIMXl7NAKoZK8xeyIRuG7oNj8qWhNMtTSvDyNqk2UCIGgVWi0ldwN3Pviz\n"\
    "tbWKcnYxvv5sedtT8pcRtV/MB5drAiBZSqkW9Ha37EObdrctWBvBvHtUp8k9XOy6\n"\
    "1X0wxUy5BQ==\n"\
    "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

const char *cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"\
    "MIIB2jCCAYSgAwIBAgIIU3U2E0/GMUowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwGjEYMBYGA1UE\n"\
    "AwwPU3RyYWlnaHQgUm9vdENBMB4XDTIwMTExNTAwMDAwMFoXDTQwMTExNTAwMDAw\n"\
    "MFowGjEYMBYGA1UEAwwPU3RyYWlnaHQgU2VydmVyMFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD\n"\
    "SwAwSAJBAIQ9BSjXR/dXPFYrNE+z5Ytxq2/gTOcQNVf4jUxnq+VksCZQGm+pSejT\n"\
    "Ye0deQFzju1zgzrOfIpJhKoFosGnEH8CAwEAAaOBrTCBqjBJBgNVHSMEQjBAgBSD\n"\
    "hOKzs+3Mo56OeliOMM0gQZgafKEepBwwGjEYMBYGA1UEAwwPU3RyYWlnaHQgUm9v\n"\
    "dENBgghnEtSASbZ0HDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUGroKNtRTXQ7nxeYSQlZq35oVQDQwDAYD\n"\
    "VR0TAQH/BAIwADATBgNVHSUEDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDATAbBgNVHREEFDASggZzZXJ2\n"\
    "ZXKCCHN0cmFpZ2h0MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA0EAO02jJwxokR4CeA8DDJqp/9Qk\n"\
    "0dim//+cjVTjxqIgUS5ykNW2CAIRuP5rVyzNv6U02F0q92Vs/754/ep+TyT70w==\n"\
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
```

Comment: The algorithm used in the certificate is too weak, i.e. SHA-1 signature or similar. How to best deal with this depends on what ways you have. The best way would be to recreate the certificate with stronger algorithm. If the certificate is outside of your control you need to deal with the weak certificate in the client.

Comment: I'm using example certificate and key, I can share in topic. Im using this certificate only trying. Did I get this error for the  key and cert very bad ? I tought I can change my security level from the python side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from `openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem` on your certificate shows:

```
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public-Key: (512 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:84:3d:05:28:d7:47:f7:57:3c:56:2b:34:4f:b3:
```

512 bit RSA is terrible weak since years. That's what the program is complaining about. You need to create the certificate with a stronger key, like at least 2048 bit RSA.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answer I've seen did not work for me or was give an unacceptable solution.

The FUTURE policy, it will cause issues. Even if you do the keys at 3072, your fix one item but many other components are failing as well. 
e.g.: Git, yum, curl , php ldap...

You don't need to go back to DEFAULT, it's so furstrating when the answer is to go to the weaker and easy way setting, kinda defeat the purpose of securing, this may not be the strongest setting, but still doesn't use the weak crypt while still allowing for lower keys at 2048. prevent error like "too weak".  
If 2048 is to low your you. then this is not your answer and you will have to deal with all the sub components. but if you just want to pass the CIS 2 compliance scan. then this does pass for me and this solution also work with the other compenents.

Try:

Step 1: cd  /usr/share/crypto-policies/policies 
Step 2: sed 's/= 3072/= 2048/g'  /usr/share/crypto- policies/policies/FUTURE.pol > FUTURE2048.pol 
Step 3: chmod 644 FUTURE2048.pol 
Step 4: update-crypto-policies --set FUTURE2048 
Step 5: reboot.

This give you all the setting from FUTURE to eliminate weak crypto but still allow for 2048 keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is incorrect.  I encountered it using Miniconda3, and it was because my cacert.pem file didn't have the target web server's certificate.  I added the certificate, and the error disappeared.  But then on two separate occasions, the Miniconda3 system overwrote my cacert.pem file with the original version (without my target certificate).  The bogus error reappeared.  But after I restored my cacert.pem file, the error no longer occurred.