# SSLCertVerificationError EE certificate key too weak

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I'm trying to call a rest service using python like so:

```
import requests
import certifi
...
requests.get(endpoint_url, data=query, auth=my_auth, verify=certifi.where(), timout=1000)
...
```

This results in a `SSLCertVerificationError` with the message `EE certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:1006)`

The reason for this seems to be the certificate on the server, according to this SO thread: [EE certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:1131)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584265/ee-certificate-key-too-weak-ssl-c1131)

I cannot change the certificate on the server and I don't want to deactivate certificate validation using `verify=False`.

Is there a way to allow weak certificates? A weak certificate is better then no certificate, in my opinion.

What exactly is considered to be too weak? I tried to look that up in sources, but I couldn't find anything specific and the docs don't say that either.